# Do "complicated" and "fiddle" mean the same?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

> 1. This blouse is a bit of a fiddle to do up.
> 2. It's kind of complicated to do up this blouse.

I've just came across the meaning of "fiddle" as "something difficult to do" and I tried to rephrase the sentence in order to get kind of a synonym.

Comment: That sense is strictly UK; (1) would be understood in the USA, but native wouldn't say it. In American English, metaphorical _fiddle_ is likely to be a verb (_Don't fiddle around with that; you could hurt yourself_).

Comment: *Fiddly* (or *a fiddle*) doesn't really  mean *difficult*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say it and it won't be wrong:

> **fiddle**
>   **3** *British informal* a small task that seems awkward and unnecessarily complex:
>       *inserting a tape is a bit of a fiddle*
>
> [[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fiddle)]

but generally fiddle is defined & accepted as:

- to touch or move something with many small quick movements of your fingers because you are bored, nervous, or concentrating on something else
- to produce false results or records, in order to get money or other benefits
- to play a tune on the violin.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember with *fiddle* is that its original, literal meaning is *violin*, and that the various figurative senses of *fiddle* and *fiddly* all derive from the very fast precise finger movements that playing the fiddle calls for. Thus:

- To *fiddle with* any object is to handle it rapidly in one's fingers.
- A task that is *fiddly* isn't necessarily complicated (it can be very simple, like threading a needle) but calls for small exact movements.

The fingers of a good fiddler playing a fast piece move almost too fast to see what s/he is doing. This is why a clever scam or swindle is called a *fiddle*.

Comment: This is great info, but I'm hesitant to vote up without any citations.  Can you offer support for these claims?

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  Fiddle is not complicated, but can require many steps with attention to detail and precision.  Complicated implies levels of structure, and extensive decision making.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say a  woman's blouse is *complicated* to do up, you don't need to follow a manual before it is buttoned. On the other hand, making something small and intricate like [Dorset buttons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorset_button) looks complicated and very *fiddly* work.

[image: handmade dorset buttons]

Certain buttons can be time consuming to close and  might require nimble finger work.

I'd say  the following [*Austrian tinies*](http://galleryofcostume.org/Written%20Articles/Buttons/AA_Buttons_Frame.htm) [the website misnamed them *Austrian smalls*]  are *fiddly* because of their tiny size. If you had twenty or more similar buttons on a dress or jacket, they wouldn't be easy to close quickly.

[image: tiny buttons called Austrian smalls]

> 1. This blouse is fiddly
> 2. This blouse takes ages to button up
> 3. Buttoning this blouse is time-consuming.

But, if you were talking about *making* something

> 1. These dorset buttons are a bit of a fiddle to do.
> 2. These dorset buttons are quite complicated to make