# What does "fiddle with that" mean

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquialisms

What does "fiddle with that" mean. Can anyone please explain with an example.
Thank you.

Comment: Loosely related inasmuch  the question is very different but the meanings of *fiddle* are also covered: [We might have to do some “fiddling”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238338/we-might-have-to-do-some-fiddling)

Comment: Also related: [Can these sentences have the same meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109683/can-these-sentences-have-the-same-meaning/109690#109690)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main meanings of the phrase **[fiddle with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fiddle+with)**. According to *The Free Dictionary by Farlex...*

> 1. to tinker or play with someone or something: Please don't fiddle with the stereo controls.
> 2. To make unskilled or experimental efforts at repairing or improving something: I fiddled with the broken toaster, but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It means to play around with something.
E.g. "The electric socket is live and dangerous. Don't fiddle with that!"